# Content after header tag is not visible

Tags: jquery, html, header, css-position, nav

I am new to web development and i am trying to convert one of my old page to a responsive website. I was trying to design a responsive nav-bar which changes into a toggle-menu in small screens but it seems that I am having any problem with positioning and I am experiencing following problem.

I tried to code a responsive navigation bar using html, css and jquery, but when I write anything after header tag is is not visible.

I tried using margin and br tags but they are not actually giving the result I want

html code:

```html
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Webpage</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <div class="logo"> <img src="res/logo.png" alt="logo" height="50px"> </div>          <!-- <a href="index.html"> <img src="res/logo.png" height="100px" width="100px" alt="logo">-->
               <nav>
                    <ul>        
                        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="" href="pages/products.html">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a class="" href="pages/contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </nav>
                <div class="menu-toggle"> 
                    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>    
                </div>
        </header>
        <p>hello world!!</p>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
                 $('nav').toggleClass('active')
             })
         })

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

css code:

```css
    body{
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-color: #FBFF95;
    }
    header{
        background: #FBB36B;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0 100px;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.616);
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    header .logo{
        color: #fff;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-size: 24px;
        float:left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    header nav{
        float: right;
    }
    header nav ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
    }
    header nav ul li{
        list-style: none;
    }
    header nav ul li a{
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        padding: 0 20px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    header nav ul li a:hover, header nav ul li a.active{
        color:#fff;
        background-color:  rgb(197, 144, 91);
        display: block;
    }

    .menu-toggle
    {
        color:#fff;
        float: right;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 575px){
        header{
            padding: 0 20px;
        }
        .menu-toggle{
            display: block;
        }
        header nav{

            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: calc(100vh - 50px);
            background: #FBB36B;
            top: 50px;
            left: -100%;
            transition: 0.5%;
        }
        header nav.active{
            left: 0;

        }
        header nav ul{
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        header nav ul li{
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
    }
```

I want to place my contents next to the navigation bar but they are going behind it or in front of it. currently `hello world` is not visible in the above code and it is most probably hiding behind the navigation.

Comment: Since you use `position: absolute`, it's not in the flow of the page. The rest of the page is rendered normally, then the navbar is positioned over it.

Comment: what should I do ?

Comment: Use `position: relative` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why you weren't able to fix this by adding margin to the main content, is because even though you specified the position of the header as absolute, you did not set offsets, the top and left rules, adding those fixes the problem,
P.S:- You had incorrect value for transition as well.
Here is the updated styles.css .

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #FBFF95;
}
/* Remember the top and left rules next time, there are also bottom and right. */
header{
    background: #FBB36B;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    padding: 0 100px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.616);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header .logo{
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
    float:left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
header nav{
    float: right;
}
header nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
header nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li a{
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header nav ul li a:hover, header nav ul li a.active{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:  rgb(197, 144, 91);
    display: block;
}

.menu-toggle
{
    color:#fff;
    float: right;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 575px){
    header{
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    .menu-toggle{
        display: block;
    }
    header nav{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100vh - 50px);
        background: #FBB36B;
        top: 50px;
        left: -100%;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    header nav.active{
        left: 0;

    }
    header nav ul{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    header nav ul li{
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
}
/* Main style margin */
main {
    margin-top: 57px;
}
```